# how to remove clear and t9 command from TextField in LWUIT 1.4?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I am trying to make a simple application using LWUIT 1.4. Now i got a problem with TextField.
When I type a characters in TextField, the commands I have added will get hidden and it overlaps with Clear and T9 command. How do i remove these commands?
Can anyone please provide me reference or sample code for removing the command.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `TextField.setReplaceMenu(false)` or derive text field and override `installCommands` and the `removeCommands` methods.